# ¿Como configurar certbot certificado ssl?

Tags: nginx, certificado-ssl

Estoy configurando certbot para mi dominio mercamira.es lo configuro en nginx ago todos los pasos pero me funciona solo si pongo mercamira.es pero si pongo un Alias ya no me funciona por ejemplo www.mercamira.es a que puede ser devido

nginx configuracion:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mercamira.es/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mercamira.es/privkey.pem;
```

Comment: Creo recordar que los certificados se configuran para cada uno de los alias que utilizas. _mercamira.es_ y _www.mercamira.es_ aunque muestren los mismo se consideran dos webs distintas.

Comment: pero no me deja si genero otro cetrificado con www.mercamira.es y le añado esas lineas ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mercamira.es/fullchain.pem; me da un error al comprabar el nginx -t

Comment: Estás seguro que tanto el apex como el `www` resuelven a la misma IP, y que ninguna de las dos direcciones redirige a la otra?

Comment: Seguro lo acabo de comprobar con nslookup apuntan los dos a la misma ip

Comment: Como comenta @OscarR se tiene que generar un certificado por dominio y subdominio, ya que se consideran sitios webs diferentes, si ya tienes un certificado para mercamira.es, es necesario añadir el subdominio www.